# Number of terms of $\sin(x)$ required for maximum error of less than $10^{-7}$

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Neglecting round-off error, how many terms of the Maclaurin series for $\sin x$ are required to obtain a maximum error of less than $10^{-7}$ in the range $[0,\pi]$?

This is part (b); in part (a), I had to do the same thing for the range $[0, \pi/2]$.  Using the error term $E_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}f^{(n+1)}(\xi)x^{n+1}$, I have that six terms are necessary, so $E_{n} \leq \frac{1}{13!}(1)x^{13}$. And this must be less than the upper end of the range, where we have $\displaystyle \frac{\left( \displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{13}}{13!} \approx 5.69 \times 10^{-8}$.

For $[0,\pi]$, however, I am unsure how to proceed. I would think that six terms would again be necessary, because the precision we want is the same. But, it seems too obvious. I'd think that I'd proceed the same way, and plug $\pi$ into the 7th term again, but I don't know if that's the correct thing to do.

Please help! If I could see the whole thing worked out, that would be wonderful.

Comment: Replace $\pi/2$ by $\pi$ that's where the error will be highest, then find $n$ such that $\pi^{n+1}/(n+1)!<10^{-7}$.

Comment: The question is how? How can you solve an inequality like that?

Comment: There is no exact method, but since $n$ will usually be fairly small, you can just calculate $\pi^{n+1}/(n+1)!$ and increase $n$ until you get below the tolerance. I don't think Stirling's approximation helps, because you still cant solve it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is more a long comment than an answer.*

If I may make the problem more general, you need to solve for $n$ the equation  $$\frac{a^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=\epsilon$$ You can do this graphically (with some approximations) rewriting $n+1=x$ and make the equation $$x!=\frac{a^{x}}{\epsilon}$$ Taking logarithms gives $$\log(x!)=x\log(a)-\log(\epsilon)$$ Now, use the beginning of [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) for "large" values of $x$. So, the equation can be approximated by $$(x+\frac 12)\log(x)-x+\log(\sqrt{2\pi})=x\log(a)-\log(\epsilon)$$ (which does not show explicit solution).

Using the graph with $a=\frac \pi 2$, $\epsilon=10^{-7}$ shows a solution $x\approx 12.7$ so $n=12$ or $n=13$ would be the solution for part $a)$ (as you already found it).

Doing the same with $a= \pi $ shows a solution $x\approx 18.2$ so $n=17$ or $n=18$ would be the solution for part $b)$

Comment: I have never learned Sterling approximations; at this point, I haven't really learned any types of approximations. Could you elaborate a little on how to solve this graphically? Even turn your comment into more of an answer? I'm kind of clueless. Thanks.

Comment: I gave you the link for the approximation of $n!$. Plot the function given by the lhs and the straight line corresponding to the rhs. The solution is where the two curves intersect.